# Making both sides of a crop the same length

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I started with this photo of a power tower, wanting to make a four pointed star out of it.
[image]
I have cropped it in Lightroom to be as centered and vertical as I could do by eye.  My approach was to export to Photoshop, rotate 45 degrees, and do a rectangular crop of the base so that four copies would fit together nicely.  The problem was that the piece of the tower hitting the edge was a different width on the two sides.  I copied the cropped piece, pasted into another layer, merged visible and this is what I got, (cropped to get below the 2MiB limit). [image]
The corners do not match.  I got by that by mirroring instead of rotating, but I would like to know how to make the cuts match.

Answer (score 3):

It's not perfectly symmetric because it's shot and adjusted by eye. Do not try to clip it, mix the branches.

Make 3 copied layers which are rotated clockwise 90, 180 and 270 degrees. Let the copies have layer blending mode = Darker color. It takes the darkest part to the mix in the overlap area:

[image]

The layers are placed easily if you have View > Snap and Snap to Layers =ON. The whole image still needs rotating 45 degrees.

Some careful warping could fix the image for your original clipping idea. I skip it.

But it's very easy to make perfectly symmetric by using only a half of the tower 8 times. I tried it in Illustrator.

Rotate the photo carefully with a vertical guide so that the top needle is vertical and split the wanted 1/8 of the final star apart. I drew a clipping mask. Make flipped and rotated copies and drag them together.

[image]

One piece is selected to show it's made of pieces.

Perfectly fitting seams unfortunately have 1 px wide transparent zone due the antialiasing. A grey circle behind the star makes the seam invisible.

NOT ASKED: I guess the sky isn't good with seams, wires and total 4 suns behind the branches. I would remove the background and insert a new one which could be for ex a radial gradient and extended wires.